# Writing a Haskell Options Datatype for Safe Query Strings for Fixed API

Tags: haskell, option-type, monoids

I'm practicing "real-world" Haskell by writing an application that makes web requests to a music catalog.  I can call an endpoint like `https://example.com/search` with any combination of optional parameters like `title`, `artist`, `year`.  For example, any of the following combinations are valid:

```
https://example.com/search?title="Ecoute moi Camarade"
https://example.com/search?title="Ecoute moi Camarade"&artist="Mazouni"
https://example.com/search?year=1974&artist="Mazouni"
```

I can use [`req`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/req-3.9.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Req.html) to build lists of query parameters in a friendly way,

```hs
import qualified Network.HTTP.Req as Req
import qualified Data.Aeson as AE

makeSearch :: IO ()
makeSearch = Req.runReq Req.defaultHttpConfig $ do
    let url = https "example.com" /: "search"
    let params =
          "artist" =: ("Ecoute moi Camarade" :: Text)  <>
          "track"  =: ("Mazouni" :: Text)
    r <- (req GET url NoReqBody jsonResponse params) :: (Req.Req (Req.JsonResponse AE.Value))
    liftIO $ print (Req.responseBody r :: AE.Value)
```

I want the `makeSearch` function to accept arbitrary combinations of the optional parameters.  The two easiest options are:

- Define a separate function for every combination of optional parameters.  This is too much duplication, and too much work when there are many options.
- Have the caller pass in a manually-constructed `params` value like I defined above, but this isn't very type-safe.

Instead, I'd like to define some Haskell data types to model what I know about the API I am consuming.  Note that I do *NOT* have control over the web API itself.

#### Desired Usage

I think the following simple criteria are reasonable:

- It should be as simple as possible to add new options
- Users should only be required to define values for the options they actually use
- Users should not be able to accidentally pass unsupported query parameters, or query parameters with the wrong type

For example, something like the following would be nice for the caller:

```
makeSearch (searchArtist "Mazouni" <> searchTitle "Ecoute moi Camarade")
makeSearch (searchYear 1974)
```

#### Attempt 1:  `Monoid` and `Last`

I tried to implement a pattern I've seen before using `Monoid`,

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia #-}
import GHC.Generics ( Generic )
import Data.Monoid.Generic

data SearchOpts = SearchOpts {
        searchArtist :: Last Text,
        searchTitle  :: Last Text,
        searchYear   :: Last Integer
    } deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)
      deriving Semigroup via GenericSemigroup SearchOpts
      deriving Monoid    via GenericMonoid SearchOpts
```

However, if we want to search only by title, we still need to provide `Nothing` for the remaining options.  I can define some helper functions like below, but it would be better if they were somehow generated automatically.

```hs
matchArtist :: Text -> SearchOpts
matchArtist name = mempty { searchArtist = Last (Just name) }

matchTitle :: Text -> SearchOpts
matchTitle title = mempty { searchTitle = Last (Just title) }

matchYear :: Text -> SearchOpts
matchYear t = mempty { searchYear = Last (Just t) }
```

Further, I haven't found a clean way to implement `makeSearch` with this approach.  The complications are:

- I'm not sure how to nicely describe the correspondence between record fields like `sqArtist` and the query parameter keys like `"artist"`.
- The `req` library combines parameters with `<>` on values of type `Options 'Https`.  I'm not sure how to convert my list of optional values into something that can be used by `req` as a query string.
- I also don't like that everything is wrapped in `Last`, since I have to manually unwrap each field when the value is used.

#### The Dream

This sort of manipulation is very common TypeScript.  Here's a [simple example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoTlBALA8gBzAGdkBvAWAChkblMxgixkB+ALmSalAHMAaKrWQMwAGxSsOXXgOq0Anhii12yEAFcAtgCNoVAL5UqMdSAQMA9iGSa4AawjpMOABQXCRDk6x4PASikwbhAeMkFkADdMZHxMOE1PaRCAbQBdZABeZDSAbiM5YBg3DwA6ekYwPzIYuISS-HUibBcAInKmDJbkAGpkCDMLABMIAFUAJQBJAGELTXwrfrBi4jKoBiY-PxzkQwKi9xWRcSrq2Kh4onrG5pajiE6aXv6EIdHJmbmF8GXLu83tnbhQo-EqKTAnU61S4NJqtMFQB6PPoDYbjaazeYgRYg+H-Wi7GjhKAQMDqKDWM4XEoAKwsoFaADIWlsDPlbA5vK5SMJgGIIBwWgAVFr6CFCcXigD0kuQuAA0lR2Y4lFyeXyBcK+HQ1hUBQBBEVi6WyhWUJWc5rc+EcACMAE4AOwAFi17TA+sNQmN8sV9mVzktavEGs9ErDtG9pvNKsDdxDWogAA8gnABQBRZPnT3GtNQKAWKAAQmQLjgJGGRGAxMGfiAA).  Using [`UrlSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) would simplify even further, but that's not quite a fair comparison.

```js
interface SearchOpts {
    artist ?: string,
    title  ?: string,
    year   ?: number
}

function makeSearch(opts: SearchOpts): string {
  var params:string[] = [];

  if(opts.artist) { params.push("artist=" + encodeURIComponent(opts.artist)); }
  if(opts.title)  { params.push("title="  + encodeURIComponent(opts.title));  }
  if(opts.year)   { params.push("year="   + encodeURIComponent(opts.year));   }
  
  return params.join("&");
}

makeSearch({ title: "T"})                 // OK
makeSearch({ title: "T", artist: "A"})    // OK
makeSearch({ year: 1974, artist: "A"})    // OK
makeSearch({ title: "T"})                 // OK
makeSearch({ title: "T", extra: "Extra"}) // Error! (as desired)
```

#### Question

How would you recommend approaching this problem in Haskell?  Thanks!

#### Edit:  Solution based on Daniel Wagner's answer

The following `SearchOpts` and `makeSearch` implementation isn't too bad.  I'll look into lenses and template Haskell as well!

```hs
data SearchOpts = SearchOpts {
        searchArtist :: Maybe Text,
        searchTitle  :: Maybe Text,
        searchYear   :: Maybe Text
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

instance Default SearchOpts where
    def = SearchOpts Nothing Nothing Nothing

matchArtist :: Text -> SearchOpts
matchArtist a = def { searchArtist = Just a }

matchTitle :: Text -> SearchOpts
matchTitle t = def { searchTitle = Just t }

matchYear :: Text -> SearchOpts
matchYear y = def { searchYear = Just y }

-- App is a MonadHttp instance
makeSearch :: SearchOpts -> App SearchResults
makeSearch query = do
    let url = https "example.com" /: "search"

    let args = [
            ("artist" , searchArtist query),
            ("title"  , searchTitle query),
            ("type"   , searchYear query)
          ]
    
    let justArgs = [ (key,v) | arg@(key, Just v) <- args ]
    let params   = (map (uncurry (=:)) justArgs)
    let option   = (foldl (<>) mempty params)
    
    -- defined elsewhere
    makeReq url option
```

Comment: FWIW I spent a few hours trying to put together a solution with automatic field selection and no TH using [this type-level map package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level-sets) and overloaded labels... and gave up. It should be possible, but it requires more hasochism than I have in me tonight. =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard trick is to just use `Maybe` (not `Last`) and define a [`Default`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-0.7.1.1/docs/Data-Default.html) instance:

```
data SearchOpts = SearchOpts
    { searchArtist :: Maybe Text
    , searchTitle :: Maybe Text
    , searchYear :: Maybe Integer
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

instance Default SearchOpts where
    def = SearchOpts Nothing Nothing Nothing
```

Now it's easy to supply only the fields you want by writing things like this:

```
def { searchArtist = Just "Mazouni" }
-- or
def
    { searchArtist = Just "Mazouni"
    , searchTitle = Just "Ecoute moi Camarade"
    }
```

If you're married to the `Monoid` instance (perhaps because it lets callers skip the `Just`) you can still give one.

```
instance Semigroup SearchOpts where
    SearchOpts a t y <> SearchArtist a' t' y'
        = SearchOpts (a <|> a') (t <|> t') (y <|> y')
instance Monoid SearchOpts where mempty = def
```

To automatically generate single-field "constructors", you could look into some Template Haskell; it's also possible that [`makeLenses`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.0.1/docs/Control-Lens-Combinators.html#v:makeLenses) or its variants may get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a second answer that uses a very different technique. We're going to make a type-level mapping from field names to their types; then we'll create a type that can have any subset of the given fields and supports field lookup. First we take a big breath, full of the ambient air of type-level programming...

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLabels #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Type.Equality
import GHC.OverloadedLabels
import GHC.Prim
import GHC.TypeLits
import Unsafe.Coerce
```

The very first thing I want to do is to reassure you that `Unsafe.Coerce` isn't really that bad. So I'll introduce up front the entire trusted computing base -- all the calls to `unsafeCoerce`. I hope you'll agree they're fairly reasonable; the claim is that the term-level and type-level string comparison operations agree with each other.

```
data SOrdering x where
    SLT :: SOrdering LT
    SEQ :: SOrdering EQ
    SGT :: SOrdering GT

scompare :: (KnownSymbol s, KnownSymbol s') =>
    Proxy# s -> Proxy# s' -> SOrdering (CmpSymbol s s')
scompare s s' = case compare (symbolVal' s) (symbolVal' s') of
    LT -> unsafeCoerce SLT
    EQ -> unsafeCoerce SEQ
    GT -> unsafeCoerce SGT
```

Okay, now, we're going to introduce a type-level mapping. We want to complain to the user when one of these mappings has duplicate keys; there are various ways to do this, but the way we're going to do it is by keeping the type-level mapping sorted. This makes it easy to check for duplicates. So let's define a type-level sort!

```
type family Sort kvs where
    Sort '[] = '[]
    Sort '[kv] = '[kv]
    Sort kvs = Merge (SortBoth (Split kvs))

type family Split xs where
    Split '[] = '( '[], '[] )
    Split (x:xs) = SplitHelper x (Split xs)

type family SplitHelper x rec where
    SplitHelper x '(xs, xs') = '(x:xs', xs)

type family SortBoth kvsPair where
    SortBoth '(kvs, kvs') = '(Sort kvs, Sort kvs')

type family Merge kvsPair where
    Merge '(('(k, v):kvs), ('(k', v'):kvs')) = CataOrdering (CmpSymbol k k')
        ('(k, v):Merge '(kvs, ('(k', v'):kvs')))
        (TypeError (Text "Duplicate key " :<>: ShowType k :<>: Text " in Merge"))
        ('(k', v'):Merge '(('(k, v):kvs), kvs'))
    Merge '( kvs, '[] ) = kvs
    Merge '( '[], kvs' ) = kvs'

type family CataOrdering ordering lt eq gt where
    CataOrdering LT lt eq gt = lt
    CataOrdering EQ lt eq gt = eq
    CataOrdering GT lt eq gt = gt
```

If we have one of these sorted mappings, we can make a term-level mapping that reflects it by creating a value of this new data type:

```
data Map kvs where
    Nil :: Map '[]
    Cons :: KnownSymbol k => Proxy# k -> v -> Map kvs -> Map ('(k, v):kvs)
```

Of course, there are more efficient data structures than linked lists; I leave it as an exercise to the reader to do the type-level hacking needed to make one of those work! Yikes.

Actually, the `Cons` constructor is unsafe -- it doesn't preserve the sorted-ordering requirement, nor the non-duplicates requirement. So under normal circumstances, we wouldn't expose the constructors of this `Map`; instead, we'd expose the following API for creating mappings:

```
instance (KnownSymbol k, kv ~ '[ '(k, v) ]) => IsLabel k (v -> Map kv) where
    fromLabel v = Cons proxy# v Nil

(<<>>) :: Map kvs -> Map kvs' -> Map (Merge '(kvs, kvs'))
m@(Cons p v mt) <<>> m'@(Cons p' v' mt') = case scompare p p' of
    SLT -> Cons p v (mt <<>> m')
    SEQ -> error impossible
    SGT -> Cons p' v' (m <<>> mt')
    where
    impossible = unwords
        ["The impossible happened: duplicate key"
        , symbolVal' p
        , "in (<<>>)), but no type error!"
        ]
Nil <<>> m' = m'
m <<>> Nil = m
```

The `IsLabel` instance lets us write, for example, `#artist "Mazouni"`, for the mapping that has the `String` `"Mazouni"` in the `artist` field. The `(<<>>)` operation merges fields; for example, `#title "Ecoute moi Camarade" <<>> #artist "Mazouni"` represents a two-field data structure. Check out its type -- `artist` has been sorted before `title`:

```
> :t #title "Ecoute moi Camarade" <<>> #artist "Mazouni"
#title "Ecoute moi Camarade" <<>> #artist "Mazouni"
  :: Map '[ '("artist", [Char]), '("title", [Char])]
> :t #artist "Mazouni" <<>> #title "Ecoute moi Camarade"
#artist "Mazouni" <<>> #title "Ecoute moi Camarade"
  :: Map '[ '("artist", [Char]), '("title", [Char])]
```

If the user accidentally includes the same field twice, they'll get an error when they go to use the mapping:

```
> f :: Map '[] -> (); f _ = ()
> f (#artist "Mazouni" <<>> #title "Ecoute moi Camarade" <<>> #artist "Bray")
    • Duplicate key "artist" in Merge
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely
        ‘(#artist "Mazouni" <<>> #title "Ecoute moi Camarade"
            <<>> #artist "Bray")’
      In the expression:
        f (#artist "Mazouni" <<>> #title "Ecoute moi Camarade"
             <<>> #artist "Bray")
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it
            = f (#artist "Mazouni" <<>> #title "Ecoute moi Camarade"
                   <<>> #artist "Bray")
```

Next we implement lookup. When we look up a field in one of these mappings, we're going to expect it to have a certain type in the consumer of the mapping. So we'll need a way to check that the user-supplied mapping has a type compatible with the one we're expecting. Here's how we do that:

```
type family AllCompatible kvs kvs' where
    AllCompatible '[] kvs' = CTrue
    AllCompatible ('(k, v):kvs) kvs' = (Compatible k v kvs', AllCompatible kvs kvs')

type family Compatible k v kvs where
    Compatible k v '[] = CTrue
    Compatible k v ('(k', v'):kvs) = CataOrdering (CmpSymbol k k')
        CTrue (v ~ v') (Compatible k v kvs)

type CTrue = () :: Constraint

type family LookupRaw k kvs kvsOriginal where
    LookupRaw k '[] kvsO = MissingKey k kvsO
    LookupRaw k ('(k', v):kvs) kvsO = CataOrdering (CmpSymbol k k')
        (MissingKey k kvsO)
        v
        (LookupRaw k kvs kvsO)

type family MissingKey k kvs where
    MissingKey k kvs = TypeError
        (    Text "Missing key in Lookup"
        :$$: Text "\tKey: " :<>: ShowType k
        :$$: Text "\tMapping: " :<>: ShowType kvs
        )

type Lookup k kvs = LookupRaw k kvs kvs
```

`Compatible` checks whether certain fields have certain types (or are missing -- that's allowed); `Lookup` fetches the expected type from our expected field mapping. Here's the term-level lookup routine (called `search` because `lookup` is taken by the `Prelude`):

```
search :: forall kvs k kvs'.
    (KnownSymbol k, Compatible k (Lookup k kvs) kvs') =>
    Map kvs' -> Maybe (Lookup k kvs)
search Nil = Nothing
search (Cons p v mt) = case scompare (proxy# @k) p of
    SLT -> Nothing
    SEQ -> Just v
    SGT -> search @kvs @k mt
```

All of the preceding things you should think of as a sort of mini-library. They're done once and for all. The next bit is where you use that work with the parameters you care about for your application. So, for example, with the fields you described in your question, you might write:

```
-- calling Sort is defensive programming, in case some future idiot
-- (possibly you!) adds a field in the wrong order
type Opts = Sort
    [ '("artist", String)
    , '("title", String)
    , '("year", Integer)
    ]

showReq :: AllCompatible Opts opts => Map opts -> String
showReq opts = unwords
    [ fromMaybe "<no artist>" (search @Opts @"artist" opts)
    , fromMaybe "<no title>" (search @Opts @"title" opts)
    , maybe "<no year>" show (search @Opts @"year" opts)
    ]
```

The implementation of `showReq` has its fields checked by the compiler; for example, if you accidentally wrote, say:

```
showReq :: AllCompatible Opts opts => Map opts -> String
showReq = search @Opts @"aritst"
```

You would get an error:

```
    • Missing key in Lookup
        Key: "aritst"
        Mapping: '[ '("artist", [Char]), '("title", [Char]),
                   '("year", Integer)]
    • In the expression: search @Opts @"aritst"
      In an equation for ‘showReq’: showReq = search @Opts @"aritst"
```

Here's what using `showReq` looks like for the user:

```
> showReq (#artist "Mazouni" <<>> #title "Ecoute moi Camarade")
"Mazouni Ecoute moi Camarade <no year>"
> showReq (#year 1974)
"<no artist> <no title> 1974"
```

...unfortunately, with the current implementation, the end user is not protected from typos:

```
> showReq (#aritst "Mazouni")
"<no artist> <no title> <no year>"
```

This is fixable, but I am out of type-level hacking steam. I encourage you to take a stab at it!

Comment: Wow, thanks for your effort here!  I learned a lot reading your answer, and it gave me an opportunity to learn more about DataKinds and TypeFamilies.  I'm still digesting it all but I'll definitely have fun hacking on this :)